# Handling 404 error by redirection to home page

Tags: spring-mvc

Consider having two controllers with mappings for `/admin/` and `/client/`. Having such, I  would like to redirect all wrong URLs to one of these basepaths. I mean, in case of `/admin/asdadsa` I would like to redirect to `/admin/` however in case of `/client/fsads` to `/client/`. How can I do that? Because simple

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

won't fulfill such requirment.

Comment: You can map a controller method to `/error` and have it issue the redirect.

Comment: But how to get wrong URL in this method to know whether is starts with  `/admin/` or `/client/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the *javax.servlet.error.request_uri* attribute from the request to get the URI that caused the problem. Below a little example on how you could utilize this.

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
public String error(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    String Uri = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");

    if (troublingUri.startsWith(contextPath + "/client/" )) {
        // client
    } else if (troublingUri.startsWith(contextPath + "/admin/" )) {
        // admin
    }
}
```